# Raspi can'to connect to Wifi with Power Suply ~5.3 V via USB-C

Tags: power-supply

"I have a PSU that delivers ~5.3 V on USB-C.

With this PSU, my Raspi does not connect to the Wi-Fi network. However, with another PSU that delivers ~5.1 V, the Raspi connects without any problems.

I know that the specification for Raspi 4 is 5.1V/3A, but I'm curious why a higher voltage causes issues with Wi-Fi."

[Update]

Failing PS
[image: PS - fails]

Working PS
[image: PS - works]

[Update II]
Log:

```
May 23 11:27:04 mobicast wpa_supplicant[542]: RTM_NEWLINK: 
ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
May 23 11:27:04 mobicast wpa_supplicant[451]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
May 23 11:27:11 mobicast wpa_supplicant[542]: RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
May 23 11:27:12 mobicast wpa_supplicant[451]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
May 23 11:27:19 mobicast wpa_supplicant[542]: RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
May 23 11:27:19 mobicast wpa_supplicant[451]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=1 ssid="MySSID"
May 23 11:27:19 mobicast wpa_supplicant[451]: wlan0: Trying to associate with SSID 'MySSID'
May 23 11:27:22 mobicast wpa_supplicant[451]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 status_code=16
May 23 11:27:22 mobicast wpa_supplicant[451]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=1 ssid="MySSID" auth_failures=10 duration=90 reason=CONN_FAILED
May 23 11:27:35 mobicast wpa_supplicant[542]: RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
May 23 11:27:42 mobicast wpa_supplicant[542]: RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
May 23 11:27:50 mobicast wpa_supplicant[542]: RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=3 ifname=wlan0 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
May 23 11:27:50 mobicast wpa_supplicant[451]: wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
```

Comment: The power supply has NOTHING to do with WiFi. Indeed the SoC and Wifi do not run on 5V and use 3.3V (and other low voltages) generated by PMIC. You have posted no diagnostics.

Comment: How many  amperes do they provide?

Comment: you have to measure the voltage when fully loaded

Comment: @Milliways - that's what I thought - but it has something to do. If I swap to the other PS I get status_code 16. If I swap back - it works

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen round about 1.4A sometimes a bit less. 1.39, 1.38

Comment: I repeat "You have posted no diagnostics" At the minimum what does `vcgencmd get_throttled` show? What is the MEASURED voltage (at pin4 - with a REAL meter not some dodgy in-line cheapie). A Pi will work down to ~4V (although this may cause problems with peripherals)

Answer (score 0):

A voltage within spec will not cause an issue.

The issue will be a lack of power, i.e. the PSU can not supply sufficient amps at the needed voltage.

Comment: I add screenshots to show the output and yes - I think you are right, but shouldn't I see the under voltage symbol in this case?